# sorting numbers with the sort command

Tags: sorting, numeric

I would like to sort the values in the following file numbers.txt, below is an example

```
1.1
1.2
10.0
2.2
1000.0
```

However when I execute the following cmd

```
sort numbers.txt
```

I get the following:

```
1.1
1.2
10.0
1000.0
2.2
```

What cmd to I need to sort the numeric values appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-n` flag to sort numerically, instead of lexicographically:

```
sort -n numbers.txt
```