# .bat file: Drag and Drop folders and files (of certain types) with sorting

Tags: sorting, batch-file, filter, drag-and-drop

Below is the code that I have. It works to an extent.

```
@ECHO off

FOR %%I IN (%*) DO (
    ECHO.%%~aI | FIND "d" >NUL
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        :: Processing Dropped Files
        FOR /f "tokens=*" %%I IN ('DIR /b "%%~nI.flac" "%%~nI.mp3" "%%~nI.acc" ^| sort') DO ECHO FILES:%%~I     
    ) ELSE (
        :: Processing Dropped Folders
        ECHO FOLDER: %%I
        FOR /f "tokens=*" %%I IN ('DIR /b %%I\*flac %%I\*mp3 %%I\*acc ^| sort') DO ECHO FILES SUBDIR:%%~I
    )
)
pause
```

My aim is to allow dragging and dropping of both folders and files together onto the `.bat` file and get their path so that I can run them through the `SoX` program. (*That bit I can do*). I just need the paths with extensions.

For folders dragged onto the `.bat` file, I want the files within `path`.
For files dragged onto the `.bat` file, I want the `path` of those also.

(The files types I want to work are `.flac` `.mp3` & `.acc`)

Also, When dragging folders and files, the sorting of them is not by folder then file. After this I would like them sorted by `name`. If this could be easily done, then great.

**EDIT 1:**
I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/46956193/8262102 which explains the File not found error.
Using:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('DIR /B /O "%%~I.flac" "%%~I.mp3" "%%~I.acc" 2^>nul') do ECHO DROPPED FILES: %%~I
```

As opposed to:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%I IN ('DIR /b "%%~nI.flac" "%%~nI.mp3" "%%~nI.acc" ^| sort') DO ECHO FILES:%%~I
```

worked.

I just need folders sorted first in the list, then files by name.
If the names are:

```
1 - Pantha Du Prince - The Winter Hymn (Ambient Version).flac
2 - Pantha Du Prince - You What_ Euphoria! (Ambient Version).flac
3 - Pantha Du Prince - Frau Im Mond_ Sterne Laufen (Ambient Version).flac
4 - Pantha Du Prince - In An Open Space (Ambient Version Instrumental).flac
5 - Pantha Du Prince - Dream Yourself Awake (Ambient Version Instrumental).flac
6 - Pantha Du Prince - Lichterschmaus (Ambient Version).flac
7 - Pantha Du Prince - Lions Love (Ambient Version).flac
8 - Pantha Du Prince - Islands In The Sky (Ambient Version Instrumental).flac
9 - Pantha Du Prince - Wallflowers for Pale Saints (Ambient Version).flac
10 - Pantha Du Prince - The Winter Hymn (Ambient Version Instrumental).flac
11 - Pantha Du Prince - In An Open Space (Ambient Version).flac
12 - Pantha Du Prince - Dream Yourself Awake (Ambient Version).flac
13 - Pantha Du Prince - Islands In The Sky (Ambient Version).flac
14 - Pantha Du Prince - Lions Love (John Roberts Remix).flac
15 - Pantha Du Prince - Islands In the Sky (Recondite Remix).flac
16 - Pantha Du Prince - Dream Yourself Awake (Solomun Remix).flac
17 - Pantha Du Prince - Islands In The Sky (Efdemin Dub Remix).flac
18 - Pantha Du Prince - Dream Yourself Awake (Shinedoe Remix).flac
19 - Pantha Du Prince - Frau Im Mond_ Sterne Laufen (Alva Noto Remix).flac
20 - Pantha Du Prince - Dream Yourself Awake (Solomun Dream Version Remix).flac
21 - Pantha Du Prince - Frau Im Mond_ Sterne Laufen (Ambarchi & Sprenger Remix).flac
```

It sorts them like, (I would like them as above):

```
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:1 - Pantha Du Prince - The Winter Hymn (Ambient Version).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:10 - Pantha Du Prince - The Winter Hymn (Ambient Version Instrumental).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:11 - Pantha Du Prince - In An Open Space (Ambient Version).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:12 - Pantha Du Prince - Dream Yourself Awake (Ambient Version).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:13 - Pantha Du Prince - Islands In The Sky (Ambient Version).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:14 - Pantha Du Prince - Lions Love (John Roberts Remix).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:15 - Pantha Du Prince - Islands In the Sky (Recondite Remix).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:16 - Pantha Du Prince - Dream Yourself Awake (Solomun Remix).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:17 - Pantha Du Prince - Islands In The Sky (Efdemin Dub Remix).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:18 - Pantha Du Prince - Dream Yourself Awake (Shinedoe Remix).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:19 - Pantha Du Prince - Frau Im Mond_ Sterne Laufen (Alva Noto Remix).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:2 - Pantha Du Prince - You What_ Euphoria! (Ambient Version).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:20 - Pantha Du Prince - Dream Yourself Awake (Solomun Dream Version Remix).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:21 - Pantha Du Prince - Frau Im Mond_ Sterne Laufen (Ambarchi & Sprenger Remix).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:3 - Pantha Du Prince - Frau Im Mond_ Sterne Laufen (Ambient Version).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:4 - Pantha Du Prince - In An Open Space (Ambient Version Instrumental).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:5 - Pantha Du Prince - Dream Yourself Awake (Ambient Version Instrumental).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:6 - Pantha Du Prince - Lichterschmaus (Ambient Version).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:7 - Pantha Du Prince - Lions Love (Ambient Version).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:8 - Pantha Du Prince - Islands In The Sky (Ambient Version Instrumental).flac
DROPPED FILES SUBDIR:9 - Pantha Du Prince - Wallflowers for Pale Saints (Ambient Version).flac
```

**EDIT 2:**
Sorting fixed (Sample Code): `/ODN` switch for `DIR` done the trick.

```
@echo off
cd /d %1
echo Working Directory: %~1
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /B /ODN *.flac') do echo %%A
@pause
```

Comment: `DIR /b %%I\*flac %%I\*mp3 %%I\*acc` --> `DIR /b "%%~I\*.flac" "%%~I\*.mp3" "%%~I\*.acc`

Comment: That returns the same results. I was having problems with the file filtering. If you place the .bat file in the same folder and drag `flac` and a `doc` file, for example, the `doc` file comes up as `File not found`. PS. You are missing a closing `"` after `acc`. What about sorting the result also. Cheers.

Comment: `dir`, like `sort`, has got basic (alphabetic) sorting capabilities -- see switch `/O`; alpha-numeric sorting is not possible with these commands...

Comment: What about this where it says `sort -n numbers.txt` https://stackoverflow.com/a/12764699/8262102. What command can work here?

Comment: No, the `sort` command of Windows `cmd` does not support this switch...

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Not in a simple way. Consult [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34417346) to get an idea...

Comment: I've gotten sorting of filenames to work. See starting post. I'm not looking an exact way to do this. Any method will suffice.